# I'm thinking about submitting a magento extension, what license should I use?

Tags: open-source, magento, licensing

I was checking out what it would take to add my free extension to Magento Connect.  I noticed a list of open source licenses.  Can anyone point out the major difference?

[image]

Comment: There's some information about a number of those licenses here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236699/what-open-source-license-to-choose

Comment: @Tim Cooper, thanks that discussion was helpful

Comment: Erm many of these aren't even compatible with Magento's license (OSL).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roughly speaking they're all about the same. Each license permits anyone to reuse your code as long as they credit you, but the (L)GPL, MPL and OSL prohibit someone from doing so with a different license to the one you chose.

Comment: Not quite right.  Some of the licenses have additional requirements about how you can distribute an application that uses the source.  Quick example: You're required to distribute a copy of an entire application's code if it uses GPL licensed code, whereas licenses like BSD and MIT allow you to "re-close" the source for you application.  It gets complicated and the arguments online get pretty stupid around it pretty quickly.

Comment: I said "roughly" :-p  Besides, BSD and MIT were not in my list of "force you to distribute under the same license" licenses.

Comment: @Alan Storm: Not quite. the GPL/etc licenses prevent *others* from changing the license. The original author is free to change, remove, or even add additional licenses at their will as the license does not apply to them because they are the copyright OWNER.